# :after pseudo class doesn't insert background image

Tags: css

When I use [:after pseudo class with background image](https://jsfiddle.net/mindaugo/66tLv43v/1/), it doesn't shows in my div. 
Why does it happen?

P.S. When I apply position:absolute top:0, right:0, I can see the image.

```
<div class="vienas">abra kadabra</div>
```

```css
.vienas {
height:200px;
border: 1px solid black;
position: relative;
}

div::after {
content:" ";
background: url(http://www.apicius.es/wp-content/uploads/2012/07/IMG-20120714-009211.jpg);
width:100px;
height: 100px;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By default pseudo-elements are set to display `inline`. Because of this, your `width` and `height` properties will not have any affect on the element and it will instead default to the width and height of the inner content.

You need to set it to `display: block` instead:

```css
div::after {
  ...
  display: block;
}
```

[**JSFiddle demo**](https://jsfiddle.net/66tLv43v/2/).

Comment: But why the image shows, when I apply position:absolute?

Comment: @Mindaugo It wouldn't make sense to absolutely position an inline element, so CSS makes absolutely positioned elements block-level elements automatically.

Answer (score 0):

Try like this: **[Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/66tLv43v/4/)**

**CSS:**

```
div:after {
    content:"";
    background: url("http://www.apicius.es/wp-content/uploads/2012/07/IMG-20120714-009211.jpg") no-repeat -100px -100px fixed;
    width:100px;
    height: 100px;
    top: 10px;
    right: 5px;
    position: absolute;
    display: inline-block;
}
```